# How to determine a function is bounded variation function on the real line?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I know that on a **compact subset** of the real line:
continuous differentiable $\subset$ Lipschitz continuous $\subset$ abosolutely continuous $\subset$ bounded variation

Is there any theorem or criteria for determining whether a function is bounded variation function on the **real line**?

Or we can only prove or disprove from the definition?

For example: $f(x) = x + \sin(x)$

Comment: It is sufficient to observe that $f$ is continuously differentiable with a bounded derivative.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $f(x)=x$ is not a bounded variation function on the real line right?

Comment: Oh, whoops.  I was thinking of bounded open intervals.

Comment: For continuously differentiable functions, we could use the criterion
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f'(x)|\,dx < \infty
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes but it seems that this sufficient condition helps little to the example I gave here.

Comment: The condition is also necessary.  For a continuously differentiable function, we have
$$
V_a^b f = \int_a^b |f'(x)|\,dx
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so in the case I gave here $f$ is not a bounded variation function on the real line right?

Comment: That's right. ${}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I notice that the formula holds for bounded interval $[a,b]$, you mean the formula still holds even we have unbounded intervals?

Comment: Absolutely, just take the limit as $a$ and $b$ go to $\pm \infty$.